How do I toggle at content level Craft 5 Multisite
I am in the process of developing a Craft 5 MultiSite website where each site has its own domain, but they all use the same template. I have set all my fields to be translatable for each site. How can I switch in the CMS panel to edit the content of an entry for each individual site, considering all sites are using the same entry?

Entries in sections that are enabled for multiple sites will have a site switcher menu in the breadcrumbs:

You can enable an entry in additional sites using the Status section in the sidebar:

